# CSS not working in mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

http://mpkosis28.com/28cup

The site looks perfect when viewed from a laptop or a desktop. But when I tried to access it through my phone, it doesn't recognize the css file from the site and only loads the html portion. Read through other similar questions but they don't seem to have the same problem as I do. Any advice on how to fix it?

BTW, If you guys need the codes:

[Here is a sample css file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rjsm4rgpmmrbwe/event.css)

EDIT: I use an android 4.2 phone, native browser

Comment: sample html file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8fb87jpdpdjzmq/event.html

Comment: Start of with putting a `doctype` in your HTML And use `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` instead of `<style type="text/css" media="all">@import "css/style.css" </style>`. That might solve the problem

Comment: Which phone? Which browser? There are still too many differences between the mobile browsers. If you are testing on the native Android browser on an older Android version for example, you are limited to not use each modern CSS rule.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use the following structure

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pruebas</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleslocation/style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <!--Content here-->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to you and @putvande for solving my problem! Thank you! :D

Comment: 1Up for this
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">

Comment: I got a warning saying "Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead." in my Chrome console. I had to change the first semicolon to a comma and remove the second semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you're telling the browser to set the viewport to the device width. Just define the meta content in your document head as such:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hitting this issue:

http://css-tricks.com/css-tricks-chronicle-vol-iv/

Some mobile browsers need this format for imports:

@import url("css/style.css");

Comment: Silly question, would this be added in the header tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not solved this problem I was experiencing the same issue and the problem is the `@media` query isnt closed properly so it applies to all the styles below it and will only show on the screen resolution that isn't closed so you gotta close the tag properly, just do a cross check.

Answer (score 0):

I just cleared my cache, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is because of android's security measures that modify file paths when you open an html file with a mobile browser. for workarounds try to use internal css, install a mobile text editor with built in web viewer or setup a simple localhost http server. For details on how to use those alternatives, visit this article page
https://nungo.site/guide/css-and-images-not-applying-on-mobile-browsers/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).