# How to test HTML/CSS files from PC on mobile device

Tags: html, css, file, mobile

Here's the situation:

I have a folder on my PC containing a single HTML file, a CSS file, and an images folder. I've been testing it through the browser on my PC, but I wanted to run the same files off my Android to test on mobile. I zipped the entire folder, emailed it to myself, and then downloaded it and unzipped it on my Android. When I click on the HTML file I can open the page on the mobile browser, but it appears that the CSS file is not loading at all, despite all of the files still being in the same folder together on my phone. Is there an obvious problem I'm missing?

Comment: This link might help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968677/css-not-working-in-mobile-browsers/21970871](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968677/css-not-working-in-mobile-browsers/21970871)

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is coming from your phone and not the file, try to upload it on a free web host, like byethost, and open it directly trought internet.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get your files into a web server.

If you don't have an external site you can use, you can still do it with a local web server.  Depending on your OS, options for a local web server include IIS, Apache (via XAMPP on Windows), or even debug mode from an IDE like Visual Studio.

Next, get a tunnelling service like ngrok or localtunnel.  When you run it, it will give you a temporary external website address that redirects to your local web server.  You can then use your mobile device to test.

Comment: I don't know if any of those options work with Android OS, but I get the point that I need a local web server. I will take a look and see what works but this is helpful. Thank you.