# CSS external stylesheet in same folder works in Computer but not in Phone ........ Can anyone help me?

Tags: html, css

I linked external stylesheet to my html page.....it is working in my PC but when I copied whole folder containing both HTML & CSS files in my phone , CSS is not applying to my html page in Google Chrome......

Comment: There are many possible reasons! Most likely something to do how the path to the css is formated parsed.
Can you at least post the line in which you "link" the CSS to your html?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS not working in mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968677/css-not-working-in-mobile-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

It may not necessarily be the problem of phone. To make sure first try it on other phone. If It works it means the problem is with caching in browser.  To solve it, open the inspect element with Ctrl + Shift + I, now long press the reload button and choose hard reload. I hope it helps you. It would give me great satisfaction if you just write that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

*RECOMMENDED*

If you want **to test how your website looks in a real phone without publishing it** you don't need to copy the assets, you can use parcel bundler, webpack, rollup or any other bundler to mount a local server that serves this front-end webpage.

Then if your smartphone is connected to the same network than your PC **you can see it in real time** simply entering the IP of your PC and the port that you've set to the bundler (or the default it uses).

So if you use Parcel you may see your app in you PC consuming http://localhost:1234
and in your phone navigating to (i.e.): 192.168.0.112:1234

you can check your PC's IP with ipconfig (on windows) or ifconfig (on linux).

**!!** if this does not work just make sure your Wi-Fi is not isolated from the wired network (Wireless Isolation, sometimes called Client or AP Isolation in your router advanced config) unless both devices are on Wi-Fi.

---

**basic instructions:**
run `npm init -y` (if you don't have a package.json)
run `npm i --save-dev parcel-bundler`
finally run `parcel index.html`

```
npm init -y
npm i --save-dev parcel-bundler
parcel index.html
```

The first time it will **autodetect** if you are using JS, SCSS, and so on and will add the required libs to node_modules so it will be slower (some seconds), the next time you run the `parcel index.html` command it will be faster. I recommend **Parcel** as it handles almost all **out of the box.**

---

***As OPTION B***

you can also share a folder with the network from your PC so it will be available from your smartphone using any App that allows that such Solid Explorer.

---

If you still want to move your web to your phone, make sure the permissions of the files are ok and that the paths you've set are relative and valid.